# Accessing Buffer from its hexAddress

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have `hexAddress i.e. Buffer.hexAddress()` of Buffer. I want its value at that memory location , is it possible.

if yes then how ?. does anyone have idea how to get the buffer from its hex address.

Comment: can you post your code with what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @vinothh I have Buffer.from('some value') at one end I mean client end , and I have the address of this Buffer i.e Buffer.hexAddress()  at server end. now I want to get the same buffer using  that `hexAddress`

Comment: if the value you have at server looks like 68656c6c6f , try using Buffer.from('68656c6c6f', 'hex'); in the server.

Comment: their is difference between this two `hexAddress()` and `Buffer.from(,'hex')` first one will return address of the buffer and second one create a buffer of data given and encode that data into hex format so both are different